# Issues with creating subplots for multiple datasets with matplotlib

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, matplotlib

I am trying to make plots of (Force vs. Time) and (Position vs. Time) for 14 data frames on one set of two subplots but it keeps coming out as single subplots. So now I have 14 sets of subplots but I just want all plotted in one set of subplots. Please help me fix it!

preview of the datasets: https://i.stack.imgur.com/bJF2E.jpg

I tried creating a loop but it doesn't seem to work

```py
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

data = pd.read_excel('HL3 Plot.xlsx', sep= "\s+|\t+|\s+\t+|\t+\s+", sheet_name = 'HL3 New',skiprows=1)

time = np.linspace(0.01,0.8,num=80)



df1 = data.iloc[:80,:2]
df2 = data.iloc[:80,2:4]
df3 = data.iloc[:80,4:6]
df4 = data.iloc[:80,6:8]
df5 = data.iloc[:80,8:10]
df6 = data.iloc[:80,10:12]
df7 = data.iloc[:80,12:14]
df8 = data.iloc[:80,14:16]
df9 = data.iloc[:80,16:18]
df10 = data.iloc[:80,18:20]
df11 = data.iloc[:80,20:22]
df12 = data.iloc[:80,22:24]
df13 = data.iloc[:80,24:26]
df14 = data.iloc[:80,26:]

dfs = [df1,df2,df3,df4,df5,df6,df7,df8,df9,df10,df11,df12,df13,df14]


df2.rename(columns={'Force.1':'Force','Position.1':'Position'}, inplace=True)
df3.rename(columns={'Force.2':'Force','Position.2':'Position'}, inplace=True)
df4.rename(columns={'Force.3':'Force','Position.3':'Position'}, inplace=True)
df5.rename(columns={'Force.4':'Force','Position.4':'Position'}, inplace=True)
df6.rename(columns={'Force.5':'Force','Position.5':'Position'}, inplace=True)
df7.rename(columns={'Force.6':'Force','Position.6':'Position'}, inplace=True)
df8.rename(columns={'Force.7':'Force','Position.7':'Position'}, inplace=True)
df9.rename(columns={'Force.8':'Force','Position.8':'Position'}, inplace=True)
df10.rename(columns={'Force.9':'Force','Position.9':'Position'}, inplace=True)
df11.rename(columns={'Force.10':'Force','Position.10':'Position'}, inplace=True)
df12.rename(columns={'Force.11':'Force','Position.11':'Position'}, inplace=True)
df13.rename(columns={'Force.12':'Force','Position.12':'Position'}, inplace=True)
df14.rename(columns={'Force.13':'Force','Position.13':'Position'}, inplace=True)

force1 = []
position1 = []
for i,df in enumerate(dfs):
    fig, axs = plt.subplots(2) 
    #plt2 = plt1.twinx()
    force1 += axs[0].plot(time, df['Force'], linestyle='-.', alpha= 0.8, label='sample{}'.format(i))
    position1 += axs[1].plot(time, df['Position'], linestyle='-.', alpha= 0.8, label='sample{}'.format(i))
    fig.tight_layout()
plt.legend(force1[:], ['5% Compression','10% Compression','15% Compression','20% Compression','25% Compression','30% Compression','35% Compression','40% Compression','45% Compression','50% Compression','55% Compression','60% Compression','65% Compression','70% Compression'],loc='best')
plt.title("Force vs. Displacement (CN3)",fontsize=17)
plt.xlabel("Displacement [microns]",fontsize=17)
plt.ylabel("Force [microNewtons]",fontsize=17)
plt.xticks(fontsize=15)
plt.yticks(fontsize=15)
plt.show()
```

Comment: You keep redefining your plot in the loop. Try putting `fig, axs = plt.subplots(2)` outside the `for` loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in Wavy's comment, try putting your fig creation outside the loop.
Here is an updated version, where I replace some of your code with loops too.
Check if this works, as we don't have your data to check ourselves.

```py
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

data = pd.read_excel('HL3 Plot.xlsx', sep= "\s+|\t+|\s+\t+|\t+\s+", sheet_name = 'HL3 New',skiprows=1)

time = np.linspace(0.01,0.8,num=80)
n_sets = 14
dfs = [None] * n_sets

for i in range(0, n_sets*2, 2):

    dfs[i] = data.iloc[:80, i:i+2]

for i, df in enumerate(dfs[1:]) : 

    num = str(i+1)
    df.rename(columns={'Force.'+num:'Force', 'Position.'+num:'Position'}, inplace=True)

force1 = []
position1 = []

fig, axs = plt.subplots(2) 

for i,df in enumerate(dfs):
    #plt2 = plt1.twinx()
    force1 += axs[0].plot(time, df['Force'], linestyle='-.', alpha= 0.8, label='sample{}'.format(i))
    position1 += axs[1].plot(time, df['Position'], linestyle='-.', alpha= 0.8, label='sample{}'.format(i))

labels = ['{}% Compression' .format(i) for i in range(5, 75, 5)]

plt.legend(force1[:], labels,loc='best')
plt.title("Force vs. Displacement (CN3)",fontsize=17)
plt.xlabel("Displacement [microns]",fontsize=17)
plt.ylabel("Force [microNewtons]",fontsize=17)
plt.xticks(fontsize=15)
plt.yticks(fontsize=15)

fig.tight_layout()

plt.show()
```